# What dead superheroes were on Earth-90?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow, supergirl-2015

The Arrowverse's "Elseworlds" crossover begins on Earth-90, the Earth that features the Flash from the '90s television show *The Flash* as a hero. A multitude of heroes appear to be dead, killed by the Monitor's schemes. What I want to know is what superheroes appeared dead on screen. From what I could tell, I could see Stargirl, Green Arrow, and Green Lantern, as well as the helmets of Hawkgirl, Hawkman, and the Ray. Were there any other dead heroes that I missed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw Arsenal/RedArrow next to GreenArrow. And the helmet of Guardian (gold version from Justice League, not grey version from Supergirl's Jimmy Olsen)

Comment: https://comicbook.com/dc/2018/12/03/supergirl-elseworlds-post-credits-dead-dc-heroes-/ has a complete list: Stargirl, Brainiac 5, Huntress, Firestorm, 90s Captain Cold, Jesse Quick, The Ray, Hawkman, Hawkgirl,Captain Cold, 'Smallville' Green Arrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this link](https://comicbook.com/dc/2018/12/03/supergirl-elseworlds-post-credits-dead-dc-heroes-/#11) all the dead superheroes are as stated below:

**1 - Stargirl**

---

[image]

**2 - Brainiac 5**

---

[image]

**3 - Huntress**

---

[image]

**4 - Firestorm**

---

[image]

**5 - 90's Captain Cold**

---

[image]

**6 - Jesse Quick**

---

[image]

**7 - The Ray**

---

[image]

**8 - Hawkman**

---

[image]

**9 - Hawkgirl**

---

[image]

**10 - Captain Cold**

---

[image]

**11 - 'Smallville' Green Arrow**

---

[image]
The 90's Captain Cold is from the 1990's **The Flash** TV show in which John Wesley Shipp plays the Flash.
Smallville was a show on CW which featured mainly Superman and some other DC heroes.

The Ray is a character from CW seed animated series *Freedom Fighters*.